# Can “another” be used with plural nouns provided periods or measurements don’t count?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, numbers, determiners

*Merriam-Webster* says about *another* the following:

> *being one more* in addition to one or more of the same kind
>   —http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/another

However, I come across such sentences as: “I am giving another three books away”, “give me another 2 flowers”. I think it’s fine to say “give me another twenty minutes” as it is a period of time, but I wonder about “another two books/flowers”. Is it grammatically correct? Another thing which seems to be suspicious is that I can’t find such examples in dictionaries.

Comment: I'd use **another** to mean **one more** and would say **Give me three more, please**, not **another 3**.

Comment: Yes, all your example sentences are perfectly fine — in the right contexts.

Comment: I think this is a fascinating question (well, I answered, so I would, wouldn't I?). There does seem to be a bias against *another + plural*, but I'm not sure the "exemption" is just time-spans. I know *"I'll take another dozen roses, please"* is cheating a bit, but I think *another + **round** number* is also "more acceptable" to me.

Comment: I think you're becoming confused because "another" on its' own implies one more. There's no restriction in usage about other numbers when specified. It means "extra" and is not tied to the meaning "one extra".

Comment: @Chris: Maybe you see no "restriction" on usage, but that doesn't alter the fact that *then another two* loses out to *then two more*, even though *then another **one*** is now more common than *then one more*. Usage does differ according to "plurality", it seems to me. By your logic, *then another one* should be ***less*** common, since you're claiming *"one"* there is redundant (i.e. - I'd miss lots of instances, because they'd just be *"then another"*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm sure there's subtlety here or there when you want to introduce it. On its own there doesn't seem to be any. The case of the redundant "one" in "another one" is just being more specific. He had five drinks, then another and then yet another. "Another one" reads and sounds better in some contexts because of flow issues, as in the case of the song with words "another one bites the dust" and in the case of "another one" as a whole sentence. Using "two more" draws on similarities. After having two more you don't know which they are. Having another two makes them distinguishable.

Comment: I always see this occurrence of *another* as meaning *another set (of)* -- so that it is **correct** in cases where the reference is to a homogeneous group.

Comment: @Chris: I'm not "introducing" subtleties - all I've done is find usage stats to back up OP's suggestion that ***timespans*** occur relatively more often (and by implication, are more "acceptable") than other *another + plural* usages (which do indeed seem to be avoided by many). Your idea that "flow issues" are a significant factor in this usage bias just seems unlikely to me.

Answer (score 10):

It is perfectly acceptable in any but the most formal contexts. It probably would not be used in legal or diplomatic texts, which must avoid any possible ambiguity, however far-fetched; but it's fine in anything less restricted than that. Here, for instance, is a footnote from an impeccably academic text, Jon B. Sherman, *The Magician in Medieval German Literature*, University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign, 2008:

> Thorndike eventually continued his work, adding another three books that investigated the post medieval period up to the seventeenth century.

And it's not a modern vulgarism, either. Here's an extract from William Burt Harlow, *An Introduction to Early English Literature*, 1884, p.132:

> By 1595 he had completed another three books of the "Faery Queen."

(I should perhaps add that this use is not confined to threes of others—“another three” was my Google search term.)

Comment: I need to point out that "another three centuries" is a time period which is looked upon as something singular. "Another three months of delay" falls in the same category of periods of time. I include an example from this category in my question myself.

Comment: "And it's not a modern vulgarism, either." [About to be facetious:] You're right. It's a traditional vulgarism, which makes it perfectly okay to use today. This is why I love the historical argument about language use. :-)

Comment: Fair enough. I have provided new citations. My point was merely that uses, not dictionaries, are the final authorities.

Comment: @BillFranke  But I have to confess that "post medieval" **is** in my opinion a modern vulgarism.

Comment: @StoneyB: It's not bad for a term unearthed by archaeologists. And at least it's consistently Latinate.

Comment: I don't see what "possible ambiguity" legal or diplomatic texts might be seeking to avoid. Surely the only reason they wouldn't tend to use *another + plural* is because it's a [relatively new construction](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=another+eight&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) that's still steadily gaining currency. Legal/diplomatic/academic texts tend to stick with the established forms for longer, but that's because they're inherently traditionalist, not because this avoids ambiguity.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  They're conservative not because they're traditionalist but on the "if it ain't broke don't fix it" principle. If I write "another" in a contract or law, an opposing lawyer may point to the MW definition and say it cannot be taken to refer to more than one other, and that if I had intended a more inclusive meaning I should have written [whatever the established term is].

Comment: @StoneyB: You example is irrelevant, since OP is specifically asking about *another + **number***, where even the slimiest lawyer couldn't argue there was any ambiguity about how many others the specific number represented.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But he may argue that under such-and-such circumstances the clause is self-contradictory or meaningless: "This calls for **another three** books, but my client's original delivery was of **four** books, so there is no "other" three. He should have written **three more books** if he intended this clause to apply." Specious, no doubt; but that's why you get a lawyer to write your contracts instead of writing them yourself, and why you can then sue him for malpractice if you lose on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Using *another* in this way forms a commonly used English phrase.

Per the [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/another):

> **another two/ten/hundred etc.**
>
> used for saying how many more people or things there are

If you're confused about the number of things that can follow *another*, Macmillan has this usage note in the link that I cited:

> **Another** can be used in the following ways:
>
> as a **determiner** (followed by a *singular countable noun*): Can I
>   have another glass of water, please?
>
> as a **pronoun** (without a following noun): We're changing from one
>   system to another. (followed by "of"): I have another of his books
>   somewhere.

I hope this answers the questions that you raise in your comments.

Comment: Indeed, it gives such an example: Another 200 nurses are needed in local hospitals. What about then: (Some) other 200 nurses are needed in local hospitals.

Comment: @user1425: You can't overanalyse. Sometimes *another* really does just mean "an extra".

Comment: But I think only with numbers as you stated. I think it's not a good construction anyway: Another nurses are needed.......

Comment: @user1425 See my expanded answer; this is a case that requires a _singular countable noun_: Another nurse is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with OP - [*then another **one***](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=then%20another%20one,then%20one%20more&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=10&share=) sounds "normal". It's almost as common as *then one more...*

[image]

...whereas [*then another **two***](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=then%20another%20two,then%20two%20more&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=10&share=) doesn't sit so well. On average, we definitely avoid it...

[image]

I also believe OP is correct when he says that a *span of time*, for example, can be treated as a "single unit" in this context. If you say *"I'll be ready in another five minutes"*, you're thinking of *a period that long*, not "five times the duration of one minute".

Google Books reports 2590 hits for [*then another five **minutes***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22then%20five%20more%20minutes%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22then%20another%20five%20minutes%22&oq=%22then%20another%20five%20minutes%22&gs_l=serp.3...4411.9269.0.9639.13.13.0.0.0.0.151.914.11j2.13.0...0.0...1c.1.rI69t2h428Q&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=ae2ba40de0d4ce75&bpcl=35466521&biw=1106&bih=866), but only 192 for [*then five more minutes*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22then%20five%20more%20minutes%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), so obviously that strong bias against *another+plural* doesn't apply to familiar time-spans.

---

I don't think there's any real "point of grammar" involved - here's [Professor Michael Swan at the BBC World Service](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1535_questionanswer/page59.shtml)...

> There’s one odd thing about **another**. You can use it before a *plural expression with a **number***.

In short, whilst there's nothing *grammatically* preventing us asking the greengrocer for ["another three apples"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22then%20five%20more%20minutes%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22another%20three%20apples%22&oq=%22another%20three%20apples%22&gs_l=serp.3...239429.244162.3.244858.17.17.0.0.0.0.66.893.17.17.0...0.0...1c.1.YG_RdO7jEYg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=ae2ba40de0d4ce75&bpcl=35466521&biw=1106&bih=866), it turns out we're much more likely to ask for ["three more apples"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I%27ll%20have%20three%20more%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22three%20more%20apples%22&oq=%22three%20more%20apples%22&gs_l=serp.3...219698.224505.0.224981.17.17.0.0.0.0.168.1069.16j1.17.0...0.0...1c.1.iSDHAKty9E0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=ae2ba40de0d4ce75&bpcl=35466521&biw=1106&bih=866). I think that's partly because we don't normally think of three apples as a unit, the way we do five minutes.

Comment: You can't trust that number Google Books puts up at the top of the first page. **A)** It's not consistent from time to time - the numbers I got were 6,230 and 321.  **B)** It's not clear what it counts. I always go to the last page offered, and the number there gives the count of hits reported. In this case it was 43 and 25.

Comment: @StoneyB: Yeah, I know the absolute numbers aren't reliable. But the *direction* they point in is true, so I'm quite happy to use them. I'd still get the same bias for *ten minutes, two days* in one direction, and with *four apples* or *seven packets* it's be the other way. So don't throw out the baby with the bathwater.

Comment: Fair enough; but there's a big difference between 12 or 20 to 1 and 2 to 1. And unless you go cite-by-cite you never spot any contextual factor you haven't factored in.

Comment: @StoneyB: I'm no statistician, but recognising distribution patterns has always been part of my job. It seems clear to me "pluralised timespans" occur relatively more often with *another*. For example, *another five minutes* seems to occur twice as often as *five more minutes* ***plus*** *five minutes more*. Any other factors are likely to be tiny compared to that huge bias, given that *then another seven* (which rarely involves timespans) is much less common than *then seven more*. I simply don't see your substantive point.

Comment: Some questions the mere A:B ratio does not address: Who uses A rather B? Are they populations which differ by dialect, age, education? In what semantic contexts do they use A rather than B? In what social contexts or linguistic registers? Is there a perceived semantic distinction between A & B? -- By itself, more A than B tells us little, and the smaller the ratio the less it tells us.

Comment: @StoneyB: I think I've conclusively established that *in the semantic context of timespans* we see "another" relatively more often than we do in other "plural" contexts. Maybe that tendency is affected by "dialect, age, education", and maybe there are indeed other tendencies that I haven't noticed. But at least I've *attempted* to address OP's question, rather than just brushing him off with "all usages are grammatically valid", which is all I see in the other answers here.